# How to check if user is authenticated without denying access to controller in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, security, authorization, symfony4

I would like to do a check if user is authenticated inside a controller in Symfony 4. Based on the check, I want to download different data from database to display to anonymous and to authenticated users.

My first reaction was to to get user object and check if it is null or not, but according to the manual: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#denying-access-roles-and-other-authorization it is a no-no:

> The point is this: always check to see if the user is logged in before
>   using the User object, and use the  isGranted() method (or
>   access_control) to do this:
>
> // yay! Use this to see if the user is logged in
>   $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');
>
> // boo :(. Never check for the User object to see if they're logged in
>   if ($this->getUser()) {
>       // ... }

I cannot use $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'); since I do not want to deny access to anonymous users either, I just want to load a different set of data for them.

So how to check if the user is authenticated without denying the access?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question: $this->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY'); should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in Symfony's documentation, you can use AuthorizationCheckerInterface:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#security-securing-controller

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface;

/**
 * @Route("/my-link", name="my_link")
 */
public function my_link_action(AuthorizationCheckerInterface $authChecker)
{
    if (true === $authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
        // Do Super Admin's stuff
    } else if (true === $authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
        // Do user's stuff
    } else {
        // Do other stuff
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Isn't it possible to also simply use `$this->isGranted('ROLE')` from a controller? Thats what I use but I don't use the same version so I might be wrong.

Comment: @LioraHaydont - Yes assuming your controller extends the Symfony base controller.  The code is the same.  It is actually quite instructive to examine the FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerTrait.php to see how the controller helper functions are implemented.